# mysql RIM error

Tags: mysql, syntax-error

I've got a problem with an RIM I have to write from scratch for school.

The thing is, any syntax checker I use doesn't give me any helpul clues.

```
create database FullHouseGr1;
use FullHouseGr1;
create table Player
    (player_id       int           not null,
    first_name      varchar(20)     not null,
    surname         varchar(20)     not null,
    addres          varchar(40)     not null,
    postal_code     varchar(6)      not null,
    place           varchar(40)     not null,
    phone_number    varchar(20)     not null,
    email_addres    varchar(255)    not null,
    points          int           not null,
    primary key(player_id));
```

the error is near create table Player at line 2.

edit: It is working in MYSQL workbench, but not in online syntax checkers.

- snip -

Comment: Try int instead of int()

Comment: done that, didn't work somehow

Comment: Those conditions are for foreign key,are you sure this is the full code?

Comment: Shouldn't `on delete` and `on update` be part of a `foreign key` statement and not on their own?

Comment: this isn't the full code, since it's a bit much. will post ity in a sec

Comment: In your full code, you still have `on delete set null` on its own.  That makes no sense.  That needs to be part of a `FOREIGN KEY` definition.  `FOREIGN KEY(date_time) REFERENCES Event ON DELETE no action ON UPDATE cascade`.  That's how it should look.  All as one statement without commas.  `ON DELETE ...` *cannot* exist outside of a `FOREIGN KEY` statement.

Comment: done that, still thesame error. in SQL, four spaces are ignored right?

Comment: What do you mean by "four spaces are ignored"?

Comment: Really bad,on composite keys you have to do `foreign key table(x,y) REFERENCES other table(x,y)` and those x,y need to be either primary key or unique.You have `foreign key tablle(x,y) references other table` and in that other table the columns have no index.Also lots of commas in FOREIGN KEY definitions which are not needed

Comment: four spaces are concidered one space, right? sice I've got "use four spaces instead of tabs" in notepad++ enabled

Comment: I've seen example scripts that didn't need that mihai. I could be wrong though

Comment: Oh... yeah.  MySQL doesn't care about the whitespace (spaces, tabs, newline).

Comment: Adding indexes to both sides of a foreign key relationship is usually a good practice.

Comment: You need to add `USE FullHouseGr1;` before creating a table.  How else would it know where to add the table to? :-P

Comment: will edit that in too... only later on the evening

Comment: added     'USE FullHouseGr1;' didn't solve it, I googled and now I understand you have to select a table first, but I still get thesame error :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After creating the database, and *before* creating any tables, you need to tell MySQL where you want those tables created.

```
USE FullHouseGr1;
```

Second, `int()` is not a valid column type.  You can just use `INT` (or `INT(10)`, or whatever number you need).

Finally, your `ON DELETE SET NULL` and `ON UPDATE cascade` statements.  They *cannot* be on their own, they are part of `FOREIGN KEY` definitions.

```
FOREIGN KEY(date_time) REFERENCES Event ON DELETE no action ON UPDATE cascade
```

Notice how that's all one line (without commas).  In a `CREATE TABLE` command, you separate definitions with commas.  `ON DELETE SET NULL` must be part of a `FOREIGN KEY` definitions, it's not its own definition.

Comment: I've done everything you said. including deleting the ``on delete set null on update cascade `` and still got thesame error

Comment: weirdly, it's working if i execute it in MYSQL workbench, but not when I use an online syntax checker I get the following error. ``you have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'use FullHouseGr1'create table player (player_id int not nul' at line 2``

Comment: no, I didn't. I think that the checker I was using only supported queries

Comment: Possibly.  I wouldn't use online syntax checkers.  I'd make a test database that you can run queries on.  Run the queries there and debug until they work :-)  Also, I present http://sqlfiddle.com/  Not sure if they'll let you run `create database`, but `create table` works fine there.

Comment: I tried it in sqlfiddle.com but then the "wrong" code using cascade and stuff. still gave me thesame error. SQL errors aren't that extensive so it gave me thesame error. letting me think it was thesame problem all along when there were multiple